# Insert script into head part of the website using Greasyspoon

Tags: javascript, html, html-head, greasyspoon

I have a javascript that I want to inject into a website header part using [Greasyspoon](http://greasyspoon.sourceforge.net/). This javascript will take care of the mobile display of the website.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It's surely possible.  I have inserted a simple alert() function into specific website. I think it proved you can make it with greasyspoon.